Searching another workbook for current active text offset and returning text from 3 cells offset from found text
I have 2 workbooks. I use one workbook to track issues that I have input on the other workbook.
i.e. on the current workbook, I need to search the second workbook for a value offset by -3 from the current workbooks activecell. I need to take that text value found on the second workbook and insert the text found in the cells offset by 2 and 3 and 4.
i.e. The text value offset by -3 of the active cell is Banana. Find Banana in column 3 and insert the concat text from columns 5 , 6, 7.
=IF(E24="TEXT",CONCAT('[OTHER SHEET.xlsm]Sheet1'!$E$2, "     ", '[OTHER SHEET.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$2, "     ",'[OTHER SHEET.xlsm]Sheet1'!$G$2))

This works but I would have to use IFS and nest 66 different variables.
I have tried using named cells as ranges. And activecell.offset, etc.
I would also have to drag this formula down 32 cells.
I really would rather have a function that I can just click when I need it because not all lines in my main workbook will need this.
main workbook:

second workbook to get data:


Lookup or index/match? Maybe an example of existing data and expected output would help

This does exactly what I need. Thanks all for the help.
Sub InsertFormula()
Dim activeRow As Long
Dim formula As String

' Get the active row number
activeRow = ActiveCell.Row

' Construct the formula with a dynamic reference to cell E & activeRow
formula = "=TEXTJOIN("" "",TRUE,FILTER('[OTHER SHEET.xlsm]Sheet1'!$E$2:$G$100,'[OTHER SHEET.xlsm]Sheet1'!$C$2:$C$100 = E" & activeRow & "))"

' Insert the formula into column H of the active cell's row
ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, "H").Formula = formula

End Sub

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Here's one possible approach:

The lookup table is on the same sheet to simplify the example.
B2 formula is:
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("     ",TRUE,INDEX($H$2:$J$4,MATCH(A2,$F$2:$F$4,0),0)),
         "no match!")


I have done that too but the problem is I would still have to nest 66 functions. I am looking for something that will search the 2nd workbook for the data matching the offset cell on my main workbook and return the text from the 3 cells offset from the match.

That's what MATCH is for?

If you need to add to your original question, please edit the post to add any content: it's much harder to read anything posted in comments.

I am trying to convert this to a macro and this is what I have in VBA.
``Sub StnProbs()
'
' StnProbs Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+p
'
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = _
"=TEXTJOIN(""     "",TRUE,FILTER('c:/Documents/EXCEL DOCS/[STATION CHECKLIST.xlsm]Sheet1'!R2C5:R66C7,'c:/Documents/EXCEL DOCS/[STATION CHECKLIST.xlsm]Sheet1'!R2C3:R66C3=(INDIRECT(""E""&ROW()))))"
Range("ActiveCell.Address").Select
End Sub`
When I run the macro, it puts the cell I recorded the macro. I need to change the Range().Select to the current cell.

Click this to edit your post:  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78330323/edit
